# Database, table inheritance?

Tags: database, schema

This is about database structure. (inheritance)

Say you have `Place` and `Restaurant` and `Cafe` are two subtypes of place.

1. You can create a `Place` table to hold a common info of the subtypes.
   and create a foreign key to connect to `Retaurant` or `Cafe` instance.

or

2. You can duplicate stuff in `Restaurant` and `Cafe`

I'm coming from Django background, and many seem to prefer #2 over #1.

Is there a compelling scenario where you should pick one over another?

One scenario I think I need the #1 is when you are going to sort all `Places` collectively.  (Can we use #2 for this?)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres supports table inheritance natively.

Comment: I'm using postgres, duh.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would go for #2, as you don't have to think about relations and foreign keys and the model itself is complete, so you could just copy the database and use it for something else.
Further you just have to query one table instead of two.

If you need to sort Restaurant and Cafe, you can use the SQL UNION Operator.
Let's assume you have these two simple tables:

```
restaurant
id | name         | likes
-------------------------
1  | Steakhouse   | 5
2  | Italian Food | 3

cafe
id | name      | likes
--------------------------
1  | Starbucks | 0
```

You can query them using the UNION operator like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cafe
UNION
SELECT * FROM restaurant
ORDER BY likes DESC
```

Which will return a list of cafes and restaurants ordered by likes as if they are coming from the same table.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last sentence. How do you sort Restaurant and Cafe by like-count with #2 in sql?

Comment: I am sorry, i ment to say UNION not JOIN. I will edit my answer